# Can you add a GTK4 applicationWindow from a ui file to a GTK4 application?

Tags: go, gtk, gtk4

I'm only a couple of days into using **GTK** as I needed a GUI for my go program so this is a newbie question. Being new I took the simplest way I could find to get started and used **Cambalache** to generate a .UI file and then called that in my go app.

I put everything under an **ApplicationWindow** in the .UI file and got it to load and work fine with **gkt4-builder-tool** but in my go app I got no events in the GUI. Looking at the sample code it occurred to me that I need to attach the **ApplicationWindow** to the **GTK** app that is instantiated in my go program and I verified this by changing the **ApplicationWindow** to just a window and it worked just fine as I could add a normal window to the GTK app.

The problem is I can't find a way to attach an **ApplicationWindow** to an Application after extracting it from the UI file. The only method for attaching windows to apps is **app.AddWindow()** but that only adds **GtkWindow**, not **GtkApplicationWindow** and in a strongly typed language like go that's a "no go" (no pun intended).

You can export a GTK App right into the .UI file along with the **ApplicationWindow** and in theory if you could do this successfully you could extract them both and perhaps have them joined that way however, I have not successfully exported a **GTK** Application, **ApplicationWindow** and Menu as gkt4-builder-tool always comes up with a validation error (after trying many configurations) so either **Cambalache** doesn't know how to export that combination; or I don't know how to make it do so; or it's not really a legal combination in a .UI file.

So my question is, should I just abandon trying to store an **ApplicationWindow** in a .UI file and just build the **ApplicationWindow** widget in code or are there other options I just haven't yet learned?

If it's not really necessary I could abandoned having an **ApplicationWindow** and just go with Windows as another path.

Your knowledge and experience appreciated.

Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

To be clearer based on Kripto's comments.

Here is the code. This won't run directly as I extracted the relevant snippet in main() from a much larger program and `env, log := boot.Initialize()` doesn't exist in this snippet but it shouldn't matter to understand the problem.

I am aware that there is only one **Application Window** in a GTK GUI. The concept is akin, if not identical, to an **Application Window** from my old **Visual Basic** days.

Below is the **go code** and a cut down version with the relevant elements from the **.UI** file:

If I change line 8 in the **.UI** file from this:

`<object class="GtkApplicationWindow" id="appWin">`

to this:

`<object class="GtkWindow" id="appWin">`

The the **Go code** will open the **.UI** file and it will work but now I don't have an Application window.

If I leave line 8 in the **.UI** file as is then it will still open the file but the resulting GUI has no interaction and it only closes when I stop the Go program which I'm running in debug mode in **GoLand**. This is because to run it I have to make the two changes to the go program.:

1. Change this line:

`appWindow := builder.GetObject(`appWin`).Cast().(*gtk.Window)`

to

`appWindow := builder.GetObject(`appWin`).Cast().(*gtk.ApplicationWindow)`

2. Comment out this line:

`app.AddWindow(appWindow)`

And 2nd one is the problem because now the Window is not attached to the application which I am sure is why it's non-interactive.

```golang
package main

import (
    "os"

    "github.com/diamondburned/gotk4/pkg/gio/v2"
    "github.com/diamondburned/gotk4/pkg/gtk/v4"

    "gitlab.com/trading5124936/core.git/loggers"
)

func main() {
    env, log := boot.Initialize()
    var app *gtk.Application
    app = gtk.NewApplication(`site.TradingAnalyzer`, gio.ApplicationFlagsNone)
    app.ConnectActivate(func() { activate(app, log, env.Paths.GUIFile) })

    if code := app.Run(os.Args); code > 0 {
        os.Exit(code)
    }

}

func activate(app *gtk.Application, log *loggers.Logger, guiPath string) {
    // You can build UIs using Cambalache (https://flathub.org/apps/details/ar.xjuan.Cambalache)

    b, err := os.ReadFile(guiPath)
    if err != nil {
        log.Critical(err)
        return
    }
    uiXML := string(b)

    builder := gtk.NewBuilderFromString(uiXML, len(uiXML))

    // MainWindow and Button are object IDs from the UI file
    appWindow := builder.GetObject(`appWin`).Cast().(*gtk.Window)

    entry := builder.GetObject(`GeneralSetup.Timezone`).Cast().(*gtk.Entry)
    entry.Connect("changed", func() {
        println(`Changed`)
    })

    app.AddWindow(appWindow)
    appWindow.Show()

}
```

And here is the .UI file:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!-- Created with Cambalache 0.16.0 -->
<interface domain="ta.site">
  <!-- interface-name TradingAnalyzer.ui -->
  <!-- interface-authors Reg Proctor -->
  <requires lib="gtk" version="4.6"/>
  <object class="GtkApplication" id="app"/>
  <object class="GtkApplicationWindow" id="appWin">
    <property name="default-height">925</property>
    <property name="default-width">1200</property>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkPaned">
        <child>
          <object class="GtkFrame">
            <property name="label">Settings</property>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkStackSidebar">
                <property name="halign">start</property>
                <property name="height-request">900</property>
                <property name="stack">pages</property>
                <property name="valign">start</property>
              </object>
            </child>
          </object>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkFrame">
            <child>
              <object class="GtkStack" id="pages">
                <property name="name">Timezone</property>
                <child>
                  <object class="GtkStackPage" id="GeneralSetup">
                    <property name="child">
                      <object class="GtkFlowBox">
                        <property name="margin-bottom">20</property>
                        <property name="margin-end">50</property>
                        <property name="margin-start">50</property>
                        <property name="margin-top">20</property>
                        <property name="name">Timezone</property>
                        <child>
                          <object class="GtkEntry" id="GeneralSetup.Timezone">
                            <property name="activates-default">True</property>
                            <property name="halign">start</property>
                            <property name="height-request">10</property>
                            <property name="input-purpose">alpha</property>
                            <property name="placeholder-text">Timezone</property>
                            <property name="text">America/Phoenix</property>
                            <property name="tooltip-text">Enter your timezone</property>
                            <property name="valign">center</property>
                            <property name="width-request">50</property>
                          </object>
                        </child>
                      </object>
                    </property>
                    <property name="name">General Setup</property>
                    <property name="title">General Setup</property>
                  </object>
                </child>
              </object>
            </child>
          </object>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

**UPDATE 2**

I found a partial answer. You can do it but you need to add the **App** to the **ApplicationWindow**, not the other way around so it's a different function. Here's the way it works (It's also a little shorter as I learned there's a function to load from a file):

```golang
func activate(app *gtk.Application, log *loggers.Logger, guiPath string, appName string) {

    const ext = `.ui`

    guiPath += `/`
    builder := gtk.NewBuilderFromFile(guiPath + appName + ext)
    // builder := gtk.NewBuilderFromFile(guiPath + `Another template File.ui`)

    appWindow := builder.GetObject(`appWin`).Cast().(*gtk.ApplicationWindow)

    entry := builder.GetObject(`GeneralSetup.Timezone`).Cast().(*gtk.Entry)
    entry.Connect("changed", func() {
        println(`Changed`)
    })

    // ***** THE LINE THAT MAKES THE DIFFERENCE ***
    appWindow.SetApplication(app)
    appWindow.Show()

}
```

I'm still not sure if there's ever a case where you would export the application object into one of these **.UI** files.

I haven't found an example of anyone doing so and I'm inclined to believe that's not what you are supposed to do but I'm still learning so could easily be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update 2** has most of the answer to this question.

Additionally, so far I don't think there is any reason to add an application into the UI file. It's tends to throw errors anyway.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Right. This is a very complicated question to understand without being able to examine the code. Basically, the difference between an **ApplicationWindow** and a **GktWindow** is just that in the **ApplicationWindow**, managing things like close buttons, menus, etc. is done automatically with integration with the application. Therefore, there is nothing stopping you from using a **GtkWindow** and manually managing this.

Regardless, it seems to me that you didn't correctly understand the flow of using the components. In general, a application only needs one **ApplicationWindow**, the rest can be done via **GktWindow**. Furthermore, whether or not to use **.ui** files is a choice, although they make the work much easier, in rare situations it is more interesting to build the widget using code.

That said, it is possible to import **.ui** files within other **.ui** files, as well as import a component created via a **.ui** file directly via code. I recommend the Workbench application to study and understand with examples how interface creation works in **GTK**.

If you can break down the part of your code that is causing problems, it might be possible to give a less generic answer.

Comment: Thanks Kripto, I added the code and UI file and comments which will hopefully give you the added information you need.